# Javascript - using reduce to reverse an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Pretty much the title. I've had a couple ideas but none of them seemed to work out - I can't seem to understand what exactly the arguments for the reduce function need to be, even after reading documentation and examples.

I'm supposed to take an array as an argument and use reduce to return the reverse of the array.

Comment: What is wrong with `Array#reverse()` ?

Comment: What the problem with `array.reverse()`?

Comment: Why on earth would you not just use the `.reverse()` method? Combine it with `.slice()` if you need a copy.

Comment: The phrasing of their question seems to imply that this is some kind of task/challenge/code golf.

Comment: `array.reduce((v,a)=>{v.unshift(a);return v;}, [])` - But like everyone said, `array.reverse` already does this.

Comment: `array.reduceRight((arr, el) => (arr.push(el), arr), [])` will be the most efficient

Comment: @Bergi you sure that `reduceRight` + `push` is faster than `reduce` + `unshift`? Yes I have not done the testing, but they seem like pretty much equal operations, just from different directions :)

Comment: Joe is correct - this is indeed a challenge - array.reverse is not allowed in my code.

Comment: @somethinghere Pretty much, yes, because `unshift` is `O(n)` whereas `push` is `O(1)`; I haven't benchmarked them either though. And both will succumb to `slice`+`reverse` or a plain copying loop.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => [b].concat(a), [])
```

or with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => [b, ...a], [])
```

However there already exist method to reverse array - [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this:

```
array.reduce((v,a) => { v.unshift(a); return v; }, []);
```

Simply adding it to the resulting array (at the front) will reduce the array and leave the last item in the front. But like everyone mentions, arrays *already have* a built-in method do deal with this: `Array.reverse`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like this;

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5],
    brr = arr.reduce((p,c) => [c].concat(p));
console.log(brr);
```

...or one other way

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,[4],5],
    brr = arr.reduce((p,c,i) => i-1 ? [c,...p] : [c,p]);
console.log(brr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.reduceRight((acc, cur) => { return acc.concat(cur) }, [])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight

Answer (score 0):

```
var reverseArray = function (arr) {
  return list.reduce(function (list, current) {
    list.unshift(current);
    return list;
  }, []);
};

console.log(reverseArray([1,2,3,4]));
```